# Allow external, not-owned origins to be trusted in Android TWA

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, android-manifest, trusted-web-activity

I am developing an app that uses a TWA activity to show the login screen (and perform login using `OAuth2`).

Currently, the login is entirely handled inside our own server, so the TWA hides the navigation bar as expected.

But we are extending the login functionality to also support external authority providers (like Google, Microsoft, Github, etc...).

The issue is that we don't "own" those hosts, so we cannot update the `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file to include our own application. So the TWA activity, when clicking the external provider login link, displays the browser navigation bar.

Is there a way to prevent displaying the navigation bar when we don't have control to modify the external URL host?

Comment: I don't think this should be possible. Seeing the address bar (and secure connection confirmation) is the only way for the user to know that they are entering their Github credentials indeed on the Github website and not directly to your app or server.